# Wordpress admin plugin AJAX call (ajaxurl) keeps returning 0

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, wordpress

I have been busting my balls for the last week on the issue below. Ofcourse I did search and come across posts of people describing similar issues but none of the answers and solutions discussed seem to solve my problem.

I want my Wordpress plugin to make use of the build-in Wordpress functionalities but my functions keep returning value: 0 in the console. The JS get 'loaded' on the admin_footer add_action and executes when someone hits 'add-row' button. That all seems to be working fine. However the console message keeps returning:
Successful AJAX Call! /// Return Data: 0

So it seems to me that the woosea_ajax function never even gets called? Who can help me out here? Greatly appreciated.

```
    function woosea_ajax() {
            $data = "hello world";
            echo json_encode($data);
            wp_die(); // just to be safe
    }
    add_action( 'wp_ajax_woosea_ajax', 'woosea_ajax' );

    function ajax_js_script() {
    ?>
            <script type="text/javascript" >
                    jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
                            jQuery(".add-row").click(function(){
                                    jQuery.ajax({
                                            method: "POST",
                                            url: ajaxurl,
                                            data: { 
                                                    action: 'woosea_ajax'
                                            }
                                    })
                                    .done(function( data ) {
                                            console.log('Successful AJAX Call! /// Return Data: ' + data);
                                    })
                                    .fail(function( data ) {
                                            console.log('Failed AJAX Call :( /// Return Data: ' + data);
                                    });
                            });
                    });
            </script>
    <?php
    }
    add_action( 'admin_footer', 'ajax_js_script' );
```

Comment: Have you tried calling your API using a REST client and checking if it returns the same things ? Maybe it's not your Request but your server.

Comment: Are you using classes? Have you tried it without the 'wp_die();' just to be sure it's not that causing the return value to be 0 ?

Comment: Hi Phill, I'm using classes in my plugin but because I could not get the above script to work I moved all of the code into one file to see if that made a difference (not the main plugin file though). I just removed the 'wp_die()' but unfortunately it makes no difference, still returns 0.

Comment: I have also added error_log('whatever') in the woosea_ajax function to see if it would output to the debug.log, it does not. Hence my suspicion it is never even making it to the function.

Comment: Permission may be the reason

Comment: @MujeebuRahman what permissions do you mean?

Comment: I just found out that when I run the script in the main plugin file the code executes perfectly, so code-wise all seems fine. Now...how do I get it to run in the page I want it to run. In the main plugin php file I have this: require plugin_dir_path(__FILE__) . '/pages/admin/woosea-generate-feed-step-4.php'; which is the file containing the non-working above code. It seems like it just cannot execute the AJAX part, does not find the location of 'ajaxurl'. Any clues to how to solve this?

Comment: problem solved...enqueuing the JS and adding the woosea_ajax function to the main plugin file did the trick. Issue closed :)

Answer (score 0):

To give access on the front-end side (anonymous users), you'll need to add the *nopriv* action too, like:

```
add_action( 'wp_ajax_nopriv_woosea_ajax', 'woosea_ajax' );
```